# Proving the Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By using the integral definition of the Laplace Transform I need to prove that:

$$L\left({t}^n{e}^{at}\right) = \frac{n!}{(s-a)^\left(n+1\right)}$$

So far I got:

$$L\left(t^ne^{at}\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}t^n e^{at}dt$$

(not sure about correct syntax)

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use

(1) $$L(t^n)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}t^ndt=\int_0^\infty e^{-p}\left(\frac ps\right)^n\frac{dp}s$$ (putting $s\cdot t=p$)
$$ =\frac1{s^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty e^{-p}p^n dp =\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{s^{n+1}}$$ if $s>0,n>-1$

(2)[shifting](http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/advance-engineering-mathematics/first-shifting-property-laplace-transform) property $$L\{e^{at}f(t)\}=F(s-a)\text{ where } F(s)=L\{f(t)\}$$

Comment: {Gamma(n+1)} = n!, right?

Comment: @Gerard, ya for positive  integer $n$

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I posted the general answer as follows.

[image]

But if you know that the Laplace Transform of $e^{ax}$, then using what @lab noted is more preferable.

Comment: Congratulations, by the way $> 25K!!!$